# My app can not ring alarm when the time is coming on android q

Tags: android, android-10.0

I'm building an alarm app, when the time is coming so app will ring and show an activity (display date/time and song title). When run app on Google Pixel 3a (Q beta 4) so the alarm isn't ring and can not show the activity and on device background show the message :

Background activity start from package-name blocked.

I search on some pages about this issue and find out one solution :
- Mitigate by using notification-triggered activities

But the alarm ring and the activity is show only click into notification, so how to alarm can ring and show activity when the time is coming without click to notification on android Q ?

https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/background-activity-starts

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the last point of this link - 
[Link](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/background-activity-starts#conditions-allow-activity-starts)

Your app can start activity from background by granting this point.

**The app has been granted the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission by the user.**

Comment: Apologize for reply later. I am trying as your advice and i hope it can help me !

Comment: what a pity !  I added this permission 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

but still not working